# java interface input argument extends from a base class

Tags: java, generics

I want to create an interface that allows any implementation class like this:

```
public interface MyInterface
{

   void doSomething( <A extends MyBaseClass> arg1);
}

public class MyImpl implements MyInterface
{
  void doSomething ( SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass arg1)
  {
    // do something
    // SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass is a class that extends MyBaseClass
   }
}
```

I get a syntax error when doing the above. Can someone show me how to accomplish this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public interface MyInterface<A extends MyBaseClass>
{

   void doSomething(A arg1);
}

public class MyImpl implements MyInterface<SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass>
{
  public void doSomething ( SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass arg1)
  {
    // do something
    // SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass is a class that extends MyBaseClass
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

@salexander has the solution, but the reason you have to do this is that your derived class is trying to be more specific which you cannot do. The reason is as follows.

```
MyInterface mi = new MyImpl();
mi.doSomething(new MyOtherClassWhichExtendsMyBaseClass());
```

In the interface you said you can take ANY MyBaseClass, so you have to honour that.

In @salexander's solution the code would look like.

```
MyInterface<SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass> mi = new MyImpl();
mi.doSomething(new MyOtherClassWhichExtendsMyBaseClass()); // compile error.
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
 <T extends MyBaseClass> void doSomething(T arg1);
```

Comment: +1 - This is the best solution if the generic type is strictly confined to the one method.

Comment: There isn't any point in making the method take an argument of type `T extends MyBaseClass` unless you need to do something else with `T`, such as return an object of type `T` or constrain another parameter using that type. As it is, `void doSomething(MyBaseClass arg1)` would be more appropriate. Additionally, the OP clearly wants implementations of his interface to be able to constrain the type of `MyBaseClass` the method accepts; generic methods allow the _caller_ to specify the type.

Comment: @Colin: "unless you need to do something with `T`" -- Isn't that what the OP wants?

Comment: @Jeremy: Generic methods such as in the example allow callers to specify the type argument. A `void` method with a single argument of type `T` does not do anything with `T`... it can only use the argument as an instance of `MyBaseClass`. `<T extends MyBaseClass> void doSomething(T arg1)` is just a pointless way of saying `void doSomething(MyBaseClass arg1)` as it is functionally identical.

Comment: @ColinD obviously, it has to follow Liskov substitution principle. But I prefer not to make class/interface generic if one of the methods has to be generic, for the reasons that I do not know if developers are going to add more generic methods of different types. And that does not deserve a _downvote_.

Comment: @Nishant: You do understand that if the OP declared the method in the interface with the signature you give here, he would not be able to make `MyImpl` allow only `SomeClassExtendsMyBaseClass` to be passed to the method (as he indicates he wants to do in the question), right? The method signature you list here will allow callers of the method (for _all_ implementations of the interface) to pass _any_ subclass of `MyBaseClass` to the `doSomething` method, which is not what the OP wants. If it was, this wouldn't require generics at all.

Comment: @Colin: I see what you are saying. Thanks for the explanation.